# How to get all the controllers from an arbitray module ID in Yii2

Tags: module, controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm working with Yii2 Advanced Template, so I have `frontend`, `backend` and `common`spaces. What I need is to get all the controllers that a module, which I know the ID, has. I will call it from `backend`, but the module should be in any part, not necessarily in the same namesapace . Any help is welcome.